# Is it okay to move my MySQL database without moving Information_Schema?

Tags: mysql

I am moving all my websites to one server, and I was wondering if it is okay to leave out the information_schema because I have multiple different ones from different servers.

Comment: how are u oing to move it? via dump? then it will be OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`information_schema` is a virtual db used for querying database metadata.

You don't have to move it, the data there are generated automatically from your other databases.

Answer (score 0):

if you dump your tables structure and data (export in phpmyadmin) you can easylie import that data in an other mysqldb. and u don't need the [information_shema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) for it.

be sure to have same encoding and mysql versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In fact, the `mysqldump` tool often used for backing up databases ignores `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`  When you restore the database on the new server, MySQL will update the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` on that server.